# Powershell escaping special characters in HTML string: Ampersand

Tags: html, powershell

I am coding a small script used to send emails. It accepts 3 parameters, subject, HTML body & recipient.

HTML body is being read from a file to a string. Troubles come in when HTML code contains special characters, quotes, etc., although HTML is encoded before being passed to the script.
Powershell throws this error:

*"The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string."*

test.ps1

```
$theBody = Get-Content ".\welcomeMessageP1.htm" ## HTML !!!
$encodedBody = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($theBody)

$command = ".\sendmail.ps1 –subject 'test email' –body '$encodedBody' -recipient 'someuser@mydomain.com' "

Invoke-Expression $command
```

Comment: I believe it will be better to use . or & to run an external script instead of Invoke-Expression. That will avoid attempts to interpret parameters by PowerShell

Comment: [Invoke-Expression is considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Do not use it. Simply run your command directly: `.\sendmail.ps1 -subject 'test email' -body $encodedBody -recipient 'someuser@mydomain.com'`.

Comment: On a second thought I think that HtmlEncode is not enough for escaping posh characters. In your case any apostrophe (') within $encodedBody will be interpreted as an end of string.

Comment: @montonero Only if they continue using `Invoke-Expression`. Which they shouldn't.

Comment: @montonero: Ansgar's recommendation is the proper solution, but as an aside: at least as of .NET v4.7 / .NET Core 2.1, `'` (apostrophes a.k.a single quotes) are also encoded: `[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode("a&'b")` yields `a&amp;&#39;b`, for instance. Was that behavior different in earlier versions?

Comment: @mklement0 Since the OP has the issue it seems that there's some flaw in the implementation.

Comment: @montonero: I think it's  more likely that the code in the question doesn't tell the full story. Riccardo: can you provide minimal sample HTML input that produces the problem? It would be interesting to see if there is indeed a bug somewhere, but, overall, let's not forget that `Invoke-Expression` is the wrong tool to begin with.

Comment: Maybe `Invoke-Expression "$command"` could help? Please provide full error message. As currently presented, there is no info on error causing function/cmdlet so we can only guess…

Comment: Ansgar, I will use your suggestion as the preferred answer. Just write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression` is considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Do not use it. You don't need it anyway. Just run your commandline as-is (minus the quotes around the variable `$encodedBody` of course).

```
$theBody = Get-Content '.\welcomeMessageP1.htm'
$encodedBody = [Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($theBody)

.\sendmail.ps1 –subject 'test email' –body $encodedBody -recipient 'someuser@mydomain.com'
```